# How feasible is the production of antimuonic atom?

Tags: particle-physics, spectroscopy, antimatter

How feasible is the production of antimuonic atom (antimuonic antihydrogen)? It would be interesting to study the 2S-2P transition in this bound state given that the mass of the (anti)muon is greater than the mass of the electron, so that the energy levels are much more sensitive to the finite size of the (anti)proton.

Comment: Is there some reason it has to be anti-muons and antiproton? As I remember they already consider muonic hydrogen which for all all intents and purposes is exactly the same as anti-muonic anti-hydrogen

Comment: @Triatticus That would be the thing to test. After all a major reason to produce anti-hydrogen was to test whether its electronic transitions are the same as matter hydrogen.

Comment: @Triatticus, Exactly. Yes, so the idea is to verify whether antimatter behaves in exactly the same manner as matter regarding these transitions. We know that the Universe is full of matter. Perhaps this asymmetry between matter and antimatter could be explained by studying this antimatter bound states.

Comment: I was more asking why muons vs electrons. The ALPHA experiment has already released results which show to great precision that electronic antihydrogen acts similarly to hydrogen

Comment: Because the muon is heavier than the electron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been experiments involving [muonium-antimuonium,](http://inspirehep.net/record/281873) some time ago (1990).

> A search is described for mixing of muonium (μ+e−) and antimuonium (μ−e+). Thermal muonium was produced by stopping muons in a SiO2 powder target. As a conversion signature, a μ− from antimuonium would create Ta184 in an adjacent tungsten foil. The surface layer of the sample was chemically extracted and counted in a low-background germanium spectrometer; no conversion events were observed. The resulting upper limit on the probability that a muonium atom spontaneously converts to antimuonium is 2.1×10−6 (90% confidence). This corresponds to a limit of 0.29GF on the effective four-fermion coupling constant between muonium and antimuonium.

The results are limits, and have not raised an interest for further experimental explorations. There has been theoretical interest , for modifications of the standard model which would predict this ,  as can be seen by searching "antimuonium".

[Muonium spectroscopy](http://cds.cern.ch/record/404131/files/9910023.pdf) is studied because it is easy for a positive muon to capture an negative electron and create the atom. The anti atom would involve generating essentially static positrons, and experimentally difficutl situation to retain, with no advantage, at least at present. No extensions of the standard model expect changes in the electrodynamics of low energies, afaik, and  such an experiment would be a lot of trouble with no reward, as any effects can be studied with muonium atoms.